# How does compiler works and Makefile comes to play in case of forward declaration

Tags: c++, header-files

I came across a piece of advise in stack overflow which mentions about When to use and when not to user forward declaration .

I came across this :-

```
struct X;              // Forward declaration of X

void f1(X* px) {}      // Legal: can always use a pointer/reference
X f2(int);             // Legal: return value in function prototype
void f3(X);            // Legal: parameter in function prototype
void f4(X) {}          // ILLEGAL: *definitions* require complete types`
```

The last line Which says illegal will fail while compilation.

```
void f3(X); // Works perfectly fine
```

So is it that all header files (.hh) are first scanned by compiler and then all 
.cc file looked for syntax and symantics where we actually can define the
`void f3(X);` as after scanning through header files compiler will have idea 
about X its member function and member

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The question is more on forward declartion and compiler thing . So i thought the concept would be more or less same.
If you want i will remove the tag

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My question is how does compiler look for things in case of forward declaration works and those related to `.hh` and `.cc` file .

Comment: What does this have to do with makefiles ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't scan header files.  All that happens is that the preprocessor copy-and-pastes the contents of a header file whenever a `#include` is encountered, before handing that source file to the compiler.

So after the preprocessor has run, this example:

**foo.h**

```
ABC
```

**bar.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
DEF
```

simply becomes:

```
ABC
DEF
```

and that is what the compiler itself operates on.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't scan header files. Forward declarations only work in cases where the compiler does not need to see the full definition. That's why they are sometimes legal and sometimes illegal. That's also why you need them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning legal and illegal part . Can you ecplain the term illegal part in Which sense . Is it because compiler doesnot know how it has been implemented ?

Comment: .Is it illegal because If a forward declaration is made, but the function is never called, the program will compile and run fine. However, if a forward declaration is made, the function is called, but the program never defines the function, the program will compile okay, but the linker will complain that it can’t resolve the function call.

Comment: A forward declaration is illegal in the case where the compiler needs to see the full declaration in order to know what code to generate. They're legal when the compiler just needs to know what basic type the name refers to.